# DataGrid Row Headers Don't Align with Content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, text-alignment

I have a WPF DataGrid and the row headers don't line up vertically with the content. Any idea why?
[image]

Comment: What's the code/markup you're using to create the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the RowHeaders default to VerticalAlignment = Center and TextBlock defaults to Top. They are still a little off from one another but once I changed that property it was close enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the row height to lets say double of it's current size? It might point you that you have different alignment/padding properties set for them :) Just a suggestion tho :) And yeah, code would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe by default the row headers are aligned like that. You should be able to tell what alignment you want by saying something like:

```
yourDataDrid.RowHeaderStyle.BasedOn = yourDataDrid.CellStyle;
```

Comment: @KrisTrip sorry didn't see that it was WPF, I am not positive about that, but maybe 
            `yourDataDrid.RowHeaderStyle.BasedOn = yourDataDrid.CellStyle;`